# Calling two functions in parallel in Java 8

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8

I have a use case in my Spring boot application as follows:

I would like to fetch the `id` field value from the response with the following function:

```java
String id = getIdFromResponse(response);
```

If I don't get any id in the response, then I check if the `id` field is present in the request argument with the following function:

```java
String id = getIdFromRequest(request);
```

As of now, I am invoking them sequentially. But I would like to make these two functions run parallelly, I would like to stop as soon as I get an id from either of them.

I am wondering if there is any way to implement this using `streams` in Java 8.

Comment: Be careful of executing this code in production, sometimes one ought not to make database calls which could be prevented with those `if` checks.

Comment: This is a good point from Naman. The sequential processing assures the second call happens only if the first one returns no result. This allows to optimize the flow using probability of what call likely returns the `id`. The parallel one doesn't guarantee that and most likely performs two DB calls (race condition).

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Sure, thanks for pointing this out. I will keep this in mind.  However, here none of these two functions actually interacts with DB.

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like this:

```java
String id = Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(
        () -> getIdFromResponse(response), 
        () -> getIdFromRequest(request)
    )
    .parallel()
    .map(Supplier::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow():
```

The suppliers are needed, because when you don't use them, then both requests are still executed sequentially.

I also assumed that your methods return `null` when nothing is found, so I had to filter these values out with `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Depending on your use case, you can replace `.orElseThrow()` with something different, like `.orElse(null)`

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to use Stream API as long as there exists a method exactly for this.

[`ExecutorService::invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-)

> Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception), if any do. Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

```
List<Callable<String>> collection = Arrays.asList(
    () -> getIdFromResponse(response),
    () -> getIdFromRequest(request)
);

// you want the same number of threads as the size of the collection
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(collection.size());
String id = executorService.invokeAny(collection);
```

Three notes:

- There is also an overloaded method with timeout throwing `TimeoutException` if no result is available in time: [`invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>, long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)
- You need to handle `ExecutionException` and `InterruptedException` from the `invokeAny` method.
- Don't forget to close the service once you are done

Comment: I really like this answer, way better than hacking around with `Stream`s like I did in my answer. Sidenote: One could also use the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` as an executor service. That way one doesn't have to create one themselves.

Comment: Thanks Lino, I had no idea such pool exists. After browsing the docs, I understand this should avoid the overhead of creating too many thread pools on a single JVM. Also `ForkJoinPool` implements work-stealing itself. A good point!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be in full control over when to enable the alternative evaluation, you may use `CompletableFuture`:

```java
CompletableFuture<String> job
    = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getIdFromResponse(response));
String id;
try {
    id = job.get(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
catch(TimeoutException ex) {
    // did not respond within the specified time, set up alternative
    id = job.applyToEither(
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getIdFromRequest(request)), s -> s).join();
}
catch(InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
    // handle error
}
```

The second job is only submitted when the first did not complete within the specified time. Then, whichever job responds first will provide the result value.

Comment: Nice one! Sadly, the API around `CompletableFuture` is not exception-handling friendly.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Where is the problem here? IMHO this is one is more clean and on a higher level than using `ExecutorService` and in the same way "exception-handling friendly".

Comment: I mean the answer is great, but the `CompletableFuture` API doesn't seem flexible to me. I'd appreciate these exceptional states to be handled through the API using ex. lambda expressions instead catching exceptions like it's needed with `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis the `CompletableFuture` API allows to handle exceptions via lambda expressions. But the key point of this approach is the use of [`Future.get(long,TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) from the same concurrency API as `ExecutorService.invokeAny`, so that’s why it requires dealing with the same exceptions. I considered providing an alternative with JDK 9+ `orTimeout` and lambda expressions, but the result was way more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Holger.

Comment: Doesn't this still execute sequentially either way?

Comment: @Lino no, `supplyAsync` without an explicit `Executor` will submit to the [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--). But the outcome depends on the actual behavior. When the first attempt completes within the specified time, the second won’t be started, which is what this approach is about. But when it did not complete, the second is started concurrently and the initiator can proceed with the result once either of them completed. Unlike a parallel stream, that will still wait for the completion of all threads.